# Getting the smallest values of an array and saving it

Tags: java, arrays

Removed the 'Story/Code' behind it just to ask the general question, as requested.

Lets say I have an array

```
int[] anArray = { 0, 1, 20, 50, 100 };
```

Then lets say I generate a random number.

```
RandomNumber(100) - returned 73
```

Now, I want to take the index of the array and subject it from 100 to get the chance of occurance.

```
int value = 100 - anArray[index]
```

From here, I want to calculate if the random number is greater than the value

```
if(returnedRandomNumber >= value)
     System.out.println("Sucess");
```

Alright, that's all fine and dandy, however, here's the problem. Lets say that the returnedRandomNumber was equal to 100, it would then print out "Success" 5 times, as that's the length of the array and it the returned amount will always be greater than the value.

What I want to do is only print out success when the index of the aray is the lowest.

For Example:

```
int anInt = GenerateRandomNumber(1 - 100); // Returned 77
for(int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++) {
    int chance = 100 - arrayIndex[i];  
    if(randomNumberGenerated >= chance) { 
        doStuff();
    }
}
```

The problem with the above code (Besides for the fact that it was written as an example and is not compilable) is that if the Random Number generated was to return 100, it would perform doStuff() as long as the anArray[] variable has remaining length.

Instead, what I require is that is only takes the least likely chance.

So, lets say I rolled that 100 again, I would only want to return the value of anArray[0], because it has the lowest value of the entire array, but how would I go about doing this?

Hopefully the question makes sense.

Comment: What is an  item-drop system?

Comment: I've pretty much explained it throughout the post, however it's a system in which calculations are done to select rather or not something happens, in this case the "what happens" is an item dropping inside of a game.

Comment: could you clarify you question in *structured* and logical way. Give the question directly and *minimize the story behind it*

Comment: Have you tried something like Roulette Wheel selection? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_proportionate_selection